# Creating CSV File from string array

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from a list of object to a csv file. I managed to create the file and create the first row, however I need to create some kind of for each loop to loop through each object.

This is my code:

```
string pathDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filePath = pathDesktop + "\\mycsvfile.csv";

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Create(filePath).Close();
}

string delimter = ",";
string[][] output = new string[][] { 
  new string[] {"TEST1","TEST2"} 
};

int length = output.GetLength(0);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimter, output[index]));
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
}
```

Is there any way to create this file and using a loop to loop through all my objects and display them in file.

Comment: Your title is misleading, you're not using a List<> but a two-dimensional string array.

Comment: I have data from list

Comment: Check this link out. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Comment: @user3430861, how is your data structured after all? You say you have a `List` but you show a two-dimensional array. Make up your mind.

Comment: @Flater: <nitpick>It's a jagged array, not a 2D array</nitpick>

Comment: @Heinzi: do you mean `[x][y]` as opposed to `[x,y]` ? Is there really a functional difference between the two?

Comment: @Flater: Yes, there are some differences: http://stackoverflow.com/q/597720/87698

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
string pathDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filePath = pathDesktop + "\\mycsvfile.csv";

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Create(filePath).Close();
}
string delimter = ",";
List<string[]> output = new List<string[]>();

//flexible part ... add as many object as you want based on your app logic
output.Add(new string[] {"TEST1","TEST2"});
output.Add(new string[] {"TEST3","TEST4"});

int length = output.Count;

using (System.IO.TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
{
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(delimter, output[index]));
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want it to be flexible, just convert the output variable to a list of string[] ... like List<string[]> = new List<string[]>() and then add as many objects as you want ...

Comment: Just edited my answer to use a list instead of an array

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that obj is a List of String I usually use this

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(stringFilePath, obj.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic extension that will loop through every item in your list adding it to a new line and loop through every public property with a getter and create a comma separated list of fields per property on the line you can use my extension as per [my tip, here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1039379/Csharp-extension-method-to-convert-List-into-a-del) or [my Gist, here](https://gist.github.com/dibley1973/3032d1c33f18b188d51a), calling the extension on the List like so:

```
MyList.ToDelimitedText(",", true);
```

Full code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Gists.Extensions.ListOfTExtentions
{
    public static class ListOfTExtentions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converst this instance to delimited text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">The instance.</param>
        /// <param name="delimiter">The delimiter.</param>
        /// <param name="trimTrailingNewLineIfExists">
        /// If set to <c>true</c> then trim trailing new line if it exists.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToDelimitedText<T>(this List<T> instance, 
            string delimiter, 
            bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists = false)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            int itemCount = instance.Count;
            if (itemCount == 0) return string.Empty;

            var properties = GetPropertiesOfType<T>();
            int propertyCount = properties.Length;
            var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemCount; itemIndex++)
            {
                T listItem = instance[itemIndex];
                AppendListItemToOutputBuilder(outputBuilder, listItem, properties, propertyCount, delimiter);

                AddNewLineIfRequired(trimTrailingNewLineIfExists, itemIndex, itemCount, outputBuilder);
            }

            var output = TrimTrailingNewLineIfExistsAndRequired(outputBuilder.ToString(), trimTrailingNewLineIfExists);
            return output;
        }

        private static void AddDelimiterIfRequired(StringBuilder outputBuilder, int propertyCount, string delimiter,
            int propertyIndex)
        {
            bool isLastProperty = (propertyIndex + 1 == propertyCount);
            if (!isLastProperty)
            {
                outputBuilder.Append(delimiter);
            }
        }

        private static void AddNewLineIfRequired(bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists, int itemIndex, int itemCount,
            StringBuilder outputBuilder)
        {
            bool isLastItem = (itemIndex + 1 == itemCount);
            if (!isLastItem || !trimTrailingNewLineIfExists)
            {
                outputBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        private static void AppendListItemToOutputBuilder<T>(StringBuilder outputBuilder, 
            T listItem, 
            PropertyInfo[] properties,
            int propertyCount,
            string delimiter)
            where T : class, new()
        {

            for (int propertyIndex = 0; propertyIndex < properties.Length; propertyIndex += 1)
            {
                var property = properties[propertyIndex];
                var propertyValue = property.GetValue(listItem);
                outputBuilder.Append(propertyValue);

                AddDelimiterIfRequired(outputBuilder, propertyCount, delimiter, propertyIndex);
            }
        }

        private static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesOfType<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            Type itemType = typeof (T);
            var properties = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public);
            return properties;
        }

        private static string TrimTrailingNewLineIfExistsAndRequired(string output, bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists)
        {
            if (!trimTrailingNewLineIfExists || !output.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine)) return output;

            int outputLength = output.Length;
            int newLineLength = Environment.NewLine.Length;
            int startIndex = outputLength - newLineLength;
            output = output.Substring(startIndex, newLineLength);
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Examples of calling the code can be found in these tests:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Gists.Extensions.ListOfTExtentions;

namespace Gists_Tests.ExtensionTests.ListOfTExtentionTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ListOfT_ToDelimitedTextTests
    {
        #region Mock Data

        private class SimpleObject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        private class ComplextObject : SimpleObject
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Tests

        [TestMethod]
        public void ToDelimitedText_ReturnsCorrectNumberOfRows()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            var itemList = new List<ComplextObject>
            {
                new ComplextObject {Id = 1, Name = "Sid", Active = true},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 2, Name = "James", Active = false},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 3, Name = "Ted", Active = true},
            };
            const string delimiter = ",";
            const int expectedRowCount = 3;
            const bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists = true;

            // ACT
            string result = itemList.ToDelimitedText(delimiter, trimTrailingNewLineIfExists);
            var lines = result.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var actualRowCount = lines.Length;

            // ASSERT
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedRowCount, actualRowCount);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ToDelimitedText_ReturnsCorrectNumberOfProperties()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            var itemList = new List<ComplextObject>
            {
                new ComplextObject {Id = 1, Name = "Sid", Active = true}
            };
            const string delimiter = ",";
            const int expectedPropertyCount = 3;

            // ACT
            string result = itemList.ToDelimitedText(delimiter);
            var lines = result.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
            var properties = lines.First().Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
            var actualPropertyCount = properties.Length;

            // ASSERT
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedPropertyCount, actualPropertyCount);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ToDelimitedText_RemovesTrailingNewLine_WhenSet()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            var itemList = new List<ComplextObject>
            {
                new ComplextObject {Id = 1, Name = "Sid", Active = true},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 2, Name = "James", Active = false},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 3, Name = "Ted", Active = true},
            };
            const string delimiter = ",";
            const bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists = true;

            // ACT
            string result = itemList.ToDelimitedText(delimiter, trimTrailingNewLineIfExists);
            bool endsWithNewLine = result.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine);

            // ASSERT
            Assert.IsFalse(endsWithNewLine);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ToDelimitedText_IncludesTrailingNewLine_WhenNotSet()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            var itemList = new List<ComplextObject>
            {
                new ComplextObject {Id = 1, Name = "Sid", Active = true},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 2, Name = "James", Active = false},
                new ComplextObject {Id = 3, Name = "Ted", Active = true},
            };
            const string delimiter = ",";
            const bool trimTrailingNewLineIfExists = false;

            // ACT
            string result = itemList.ToDelimitedText(delimiter, trimTrailingNewLineIfExists);
            bool endsWithNewLine = result.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine);

            // ASSERT
            Assert.IsTrue(endsWithNewLine);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass each string array collection  to this function and this will return a CSV formatted string that you can either save to a large string buffer or write line by line to a file.

C#

```
public string CSVout(string[] strArray)
{
    string sOut = "";

    foreach (void s_loopVariable in strArray) {
        s = s_loopVariable;
        if (s.Contains(","))
            s = Strings.Chr(34) + s + Strings.Chr(34);
        sOut += s + ",";
    }

    if (Strings.Right(sOut, 1) == ",")
        sOut = Strings.Left(@out, @out.Length - 1);

    return sOut;
}
```

VB.NET:

```
  Function CSVout(strArray() As String) As String
    Dim out As String = ""

    For Each s In strArray
        If s.Contains(",") Then s = Chr(34) + s + Chr(34)
        out &= s + ","
    Next

    If Strings.Right(out, 1) = "," Then out = Strings.Left(out, out.Length - 1)

    Return out
End Function
```